# $.ajax request works but $http for angular returns access control allow origin issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, http

So, I have a script that uses jQuery to make a request to another server through this call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: URL,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success:function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        // success!
      });
  }
});
```

However, this in angularjs returns a access-control-allow-origin error:

```
  var request = {
    method: 'get',
    url: URL   }   $http(request).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // success!
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // error!
    });
```

Talking to another developer, the only way the ajax call started working was by adding the **dataType : 'jsonp'** parameter to the call. It returns the same error in $.ajax otherwise.

I've tried to supply this through the **'Accept'** header field in the request variable as well as changing the method from **get** to **jsonp** but it didn't work. Is there a particular parameter I can pass to the $http request that is similar to the dataType: jsonp in thr $.ajax call that would get this working?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp searched using **angular jsonp** to find this result.

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that I tried this and it didn't work. I receive a 404 error when the method is changed from get to jsonp. I can access the URL and the data through the browser so the 404 error is confusing.

Comment: I didn't say to change the method to jsonp, that doesn't seem to be documented. There's a separate $http.jsonp method that you can use.

Comment: There is a working example at the bottom that uses JSONP as the method

Comment: I believe we are referring to the same method here. You can either call it directly via **$http.jsonp()** or change the request variable method parameter from **get** to **jsonp** in the code above.

Comment: Possibly. What i'm getting at is the example works, and your jquery attempt works, so you must be doing something wrong with your angular attempt. It clearly works in the demo.

Comment: I can say that doing *"I've tried to supply this through the 'Accept' header field"* is absolutely not necessary and should have no affect on a jsonp request because you cannot set headers on a jsonp request. Doing so may be making angular use GET instead of JSONP.

Comment: Also note that in the example, `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` was added to the url, where that would have been left out in your jQuery attempt. all of these are things that you haven't shown in your question yet.

Comment: Woot! Changing the method to **jsonp** and adding **?callback=JSON_CALLBACK** at the end of the URL worked! Would you like to submit that as an official answer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, it will automatically add a `callback=somethng` to the url which is required for properly written jsonp services. Angular doesn't do this automatically, instead it requires you to add the parameter yourself with a value of `JSONP_CALLBACK` that angular will then replace with it's own callback name.

```
http://domain.com/myservice?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK
```